# Настройка логера winston

Tags: node.js, логирование, backend

Всем привет

Есть старый способ использование логера winston. (версия ниже 2.4.4 )

```js
  var winston = require('winston');
 
  //
  // Configure CLI output on the default logger
  //
  winston.cli();
```

На данный момент версия winston: 3.3.3.

```js
const winston = require('winston');

const myformat = winston.format.cli({ colors: { info: 'green' }});


const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            format: myformat
        })
    ]
});

winston.add(logger)
```

C таким способом вывод такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто знает как нужно инициализировать winston чтобы преобразовать  "%s: %s" в нормальный текст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно добавить поле формат

```js
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  format: winston.format.splat(),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format
    })
  ]
});
```